# How to use a variable as a JSON file name when using getJSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables, getjson

I'm trying to develop a simple way to turn a .json file into an HTML table using javascript.

I've tried using a file upload input, text input, html form, as well as appending data from one .json file to another empty container .json file. The main thing(s) I'm trying to fix are located on lines 3, 5, and 17.

What I want to happen is the user inputs the name of the .json file via the text field (or just uploads the file), and the program turns it into an html table, but I can't figure out how to use a variable to implement that.

````
<script>

    $(function() {
var whatname = document.getElementById("whatnametext")

   var people = [];

   $.getJSON(whatname, function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="whatnametext">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>```
````

Comment: To your specific question, I will give you a hint. var whatname = document.getElementById("whatnametext"). This just gives the element, not its value.

Comment: @Krishna Teja Veeramachaneni thanks, that worked, I found that you also need to refresh the page to get it to update as well.

Comment: The code runs when the page loads. You should probably put it into an event handler so it runs when the user clicks on something after filling in the text field.